# Filter three drop down and upload data to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

By using this code I am creating two drop down and one the basis of first ,trying to filter second , 
If I select Software issue in first drop down, in second drop down only two data I want, master data and App crash. same ins hardware only 2 printer and machine.
once select printer in second one then only one data print not coming in third drop down.

```
  <tr>
    <td>
        <b>Issue</b>
        <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="select-native-1" id="store_issue" data-iconpos="left">
        <option value="No Issue">No Issue</option>
        <option value="Software Issue">Software Issue</option>
        <option value="Hardware Issue">Hardware Issue</option>

      </select>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Type</b>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td>
           <select name="select-native-2" id="store_issue_type" data-iconpos="left">

           <option value="Master data">Master data</option>
           <option value="crash">App Crash</option>
           <option value="Printer">Printer</option>
           <option value="Machine">Machine</option>

      </select>
       <br>
       </td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Details</b>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td>
           <select name="select-native-3" id="store_issue_details" data-iconpos="left">

           <option value="data ussue">Data Isse</option>
           <option value="App crash">App crash</option>
           <option value="print not coming">Print not coming</option>
           <option value="Machine not getting on">Machine not getting on</option>

      </select>
         <br>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Below is my js code.. , but it's not vorking

```
    <script>

$("#select1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select2').html(options);
});

    </script>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and remember that SO is not a coding service

Comment: You need to use jquery `.change()` function https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: There's no `select` elements  on your html code that have id select1 or select2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically add and remove options from other selects using jQuery easily. Just to give you an idea here is an example;

```js
$(function() {

 $('#store_issue').on('change', function() {
   $('#store_issue_type').empty();
    $('#store_issue_details').empty();
    
   switch($(this).val()) {
      case "Software Issue":
       $('#store_issue_type')
         .append($('<option value="Master data">Master data</option>'))
          .append($('<option value="crash">App Crash</option>'));
          break;
      case "Hardware Issue":
       $('#store_issue_type')
         .append($('<option value="Printer">Printer</option>'))
          .append($('<option value="Machine">Machine</option>'));
    }      
  });
  
  $('#store_issue_type').on('change', function() {
   $('#store_issue_details').empty();
    
    switch($(this).val()) {
     case "Master data":
       $('#store_issue_details')
         .append($('<option data-sel="Master data" value="data ussue">Data Isse</option>'));
          break;
      case "crash":
       $('#store_issue_details')
         .append($('<option data-sel="crash" value="App crash">App crash</option>'));
          break;
      case "Printer":
       $('#store_issue_details')
         .append($('<option data-sel="Printer" value="print not coming">Print not coming</option>'));
          break;
      case "Machine":
       $('#store_issue_details')
         .append($('<option data-sel="Machine" value="Machine not getting on">Machine not getting on</option>'));
          break;
    }    
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Issue</b>
    <br>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="select-native-1" id="store_issue" data-iconpos="left">
      <option value="No Issue">No Issue</option>
      <option value="Software Issue">Software Issue</option>
      <option value="Hardware Issue">Hardware Issue</option>


    </select>
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>



<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Type</b>
    <br>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="select-native-2" id="store_issue_type" data-iconpos="left">

    </select>
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Details</b>
    <br>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="select-native-3" id="store_issue_details" data-iconpos="left">

    </select>
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sir but after selection of second drop drop data is not coming in third drop down

Comment: I thought you can fill that part yourself using the same technique.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `disable` and `enable` options based on first dropdown selection. Check below snippet for reference. I just sampled with only two selects.

```js
$('#select2 option').prop('disabled', true);
$('#select2').find('.'+ $('#select1').val()).prop('disabled', false);
$('#select1').change(function() {
  $('#select2 option').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#select2').find('.' + $(this).val()).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option class="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option class="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option class="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option class="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option class="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option class="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your valuable time..thanks a lot..let me try these examples ..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#store_issue").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val().replace(" Issue", "")
  $("#store_issue_type option").show().not("[data-sel=" + v + "]").hide();
  $("#store_issue_type").val($("#store_issue_type option[data-sel=" + v + "]:first()").first().val())
})

$("#store_issue_type").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val()
  $("#store_issue_details option").show().not("[data-sel='" + v + "']").hide();
  $("#store_issue_details").val($("#store_issue_details option[data-sel='" + v + "']:first()").first().val())
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#store_issue").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val().replace(" Issue", "")
  $("#store_issue_type option").show().not("[data-sel=" + v + "]").hide();
  $("#store_issue_type").val($("#store_issue_type option[data-sel=" + v + "]:first()").first().val())
})

$("#store_issue_type").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val()
  $("#store_issue_details option").show().not("[data-sel='" + v + "']").hide();
  $("#store_issue_details").val($("#store_issue_details option[data-sel='" + v + "']:first()").first().val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Issue</b>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="select-native-1" id="store_issue" data-iconpos="left">
          <option value="No Issue">No Issue</option>
        <option value="Software Issue">Software Issue</option>
        <option value="Hardware Issue">Hardware Issue</option>


    </select>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>



  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Type</b>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="select-native-2" id="store_issue_type" data-iconpos="left">

               <option data-sel="Software" value="Master data">Master data</option>
               <option data-sel="Software" value="crash">App Crash</option>
               <option data-sel="Hardware" value="Printer">Printer</option>
               <option data-sel="Hardware" value="Machine">Machine</option>

    </select>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Details</b>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="select-native-3" id="store_issue_details" data-iconpos="left">

               <option data-sel="Master data" value="data ussue">Data Isse</option>
               <option data-sel="crash" value="App crash">App crash</option>
               <option data-sel="Printer" value="print not coming">Print not coming</option>
               <option data-sel="Machine" value="Machine not getting on">Machine not getting on</option>

    </select>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```